# How to loop X times using XSLT 2,0?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have following requirement where I need your help to transform the XML using XSLT 2.0.

1. `<Workers>` node for a single worker need to be inserted as many time as total number of `<Days>` for a worker e.g. if total number of days for a worker is 5, `<Workers><Worker>` need to be present 5 times holding the data for that worker.
2. Each time new nodes are inserted for a worker, `<StartDate>` need to be incremented by a day and map it's value to new element `WorkerStartDate`
3. Each time new nodes are created, a new element `<RecordNumber>` needs to be inserted holding the value of that loop.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <id>1234</id>
        <loc>New York</loc>
        <Days>5</Days>
        <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Expected Output XML after XSLT transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-03</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-04</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>4</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-05</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>5</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-06</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

I’m able to get following output `<RecordNumber>` and `<WorkerStartDate>` are returning wrong data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerId>1234</WorkerId>
        <WorkerLoc>New York</WorkerLoc>
        <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
        <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
        <WorkerStartDate>2019-02-02</WorkerStartDate>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="Workers/Worker/Days"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Records" select="Workers/Worker"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$start to $counter">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$Records" mode="replicate">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Worker" mode="replicate">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <Workers>
            <Worker>
                <WorkerId><xsl:value-of select="id"/></WorkerId>
                <WorkerLoc><xsl:value-of select="loc"/></WorkerLoc>
                <RecordNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></RecordNumber>
                <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
                <WorkerStartDate><xsl:value-of select="xs:date(StartDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
                </WorkerStartDate>
            </Worker>
        </Workers>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output XML has following issues:

1. `<WorkerStartDate>` always returned as 1 where as WorkerStartDate is expected to increment by a day based on the XML element
2. `<RecordNumber>` always returned as 1 where as RecordNumber is expected to increment by one such as 1,2,3..
3. Not a big issue - `<WorkerDays>` needs to always return 1. Now that I hard coded this value. Not sure if there is an efficient way to print 1 as value until the loop ends.

Can someone help me fix the issues that I have please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined that parameter named `data` that is bound to the integer value you process in the `for-each` with the `to` expression so you can simply use that parameter with

```
<RecordNumber><xsl:value-of select="$data"/></RecordNumber>
```

and

```
<WorkerStartDate>
  <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(StartDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * $data"/>
</WorkerStartDate>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeT